# PDF with Content-disposition: inline; only works with devMode ON

Tags: assets, pdf, headers

This works fine with `devMode(true)`, but not when false.

I'm calling it as a craft variable `{% do craft.mymodule.pdf(entry) %}`

```
public function pdf(Entry $entry)
{
    $asset = $entry->asset->one();

    $fsPath = Craft::getAlias($asset->getVolume()->fs->path);
    $file = $fsPath . '/' . $asset->getPath();

    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Cache-Control: maxage=1');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $asset->size);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Type: ' . $asset->getMimeType());
    header('Content-disposition: inline; filename=' . basename($asset->filename));
    header('Pragma: public');

    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Error message

[image]

BTW, nothing in the logs when it fails.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem moving part of my code to twig.

So final code looks like:

twig

```
{% set asset = entry.asset.one() %}
{% set file = alias('@assets') ~ '/' ~ asset.getPath %}

{% header 'Accept-Ranges: bytes' %}
{% header 'Cache-Control: maxage=1' %}
{% header 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' %}
{% header 'Content-Type: ' ~ asset.getMimeType %}
{% header 'Content-disposition: inline; filename=' ~ asset.filename %}
{% header 'Pragma: public' %}

{% do craft.mymodule.pdf(file) %}
```

craft variable

```
public function pdf(String $file): void
{
    readfile($file);
}
```

Comment: Huh... really strange.